# fix line positioning in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas in a div like this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="{{ image }}" class="img-class img-thumbnail img-responsive">
    <canvas id="can" class="hidden" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></canvas>
    <div class="hidden hover-div" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.07); top: 0;">

    </div>
</div>
```

and the code to draw a line with it

```
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
prevX = 0,
currX = 0,
prevY = 0,
currY = 0,
dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
y = 2;

function initialize() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

it works but the x,y co-ordinates are off, need help fixing this.

Here's a screen record demo of it's behaviour https://youtu.be/e8SUUZF81rk

the y pos is far down on the canvas compared to the mouse and x is slightly to the right.

I got this code from an example from here and edited it a little.

Comment: It would be better if you converted that short youtube video to a .gif and put it directly with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the canvas resolution to match the canvas display size, or scale the mouse coords to the canvas resolution.

To set the resolution to match the canvas display size

```
 const bounds = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
 canvasElement.width = bounds.width;
 canvasElement.height = bounds.height;
```

Or if you prefer you can scale the mouse position to match the canvas resolution

```
 const bounds = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
 const scaleX = canvasElement.width / bounds.width;
 const scaleY = canvasElement.height / bounds.height;

 // then scale the mouse with the above scales
 // in mouse event

 mouseX = mouseEvent.clientX * scaleX;
 mouseY = mouseEvent.clientY * scaleY;
```

Comment: close... did this ```canvas = document.getElementById('can');

    const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvas.width = bounds.width;
    canvas.height = bounds.height;``` and here's how it looks https://youtu.be/trAXMcxJDHM

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri LOL close enough then.